# Java search tree algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, runtime-error, nosuchelementexception

We are making a slidepuzzle for a project for school. We succeeded in making the puzzle but now we want to make an ' ARTIFICIAL INTELLEGINCE'. THis means the computer can calculate the shortest solution and solve the puzzle.

We are making a tree so he can look for the solution. We always get the 'nosuchelement'  fault.

ArrayList positiesVoorHint = this is the position of the pieces in an arraylist shuffled, we made our own shuffle.

oplossingsposities.add(i)  = these are the names of the pieces on index 0 it is piece number 1

We also defined the UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT methods in another class and they are working perfectly.

testPuzzelOpgelost = testpuzzlesolved

We also had to clone the list because of our methods UP, DOWN,LEFT RIGHT. Don't worry about that.

(Our native language is not english).

---

This is the code which we use when we click on a button, so he makes 1 step closer to the shortest solution:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> HintUitvoeren()
 {
  ArrayList<Integer> positiesNaHint;
  HintBerekenen2 hint = new HintBerekenen2(posities, dimensie);
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> positieMatrix = hint.oplossingspad;
  afbeeldingenPlaatsen();
  positiesNaHint = positieMatrix.get(1);
  return positiesNaHint;
 }
```

### This code should be perfectly fine

Problem should be here:

Here is the code; (for some reason it wont display as code, also with the 4 spaces)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

public class HintBerekenen2 extends Bewegingen
{
 Queue<ArrayList<Integer>> wachtrij;
 Map<ArrayList<Integer>, ArrayList<Integer>> boom;
 int dimensie;
 Bewegingen bew;
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> oplossingspad;
 ArrayList<Integer> meestRecentePosities, oplossingsposities;

 public HintBerekenen2 (ArrayList<Integer> positiesVoorHint, int dimensie)
 {
  System.out.println("HINT START HIER");
  this.dimensie = dimensie;

  wachtrij = new LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  boom = new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>,ArrayList<Integer>>();
  bew = new Bewegingen();


  //Oplossings ArrayList maken. ([1, 2, ..., (dimensie*dimensie) - 1,         (dimensie*dimensie)]
  oplossingsposities = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  for (int i = 1; i < (dimensie*dimensie) + 1; i++)
  {
   oplossingsposities.add(i);
  }

  voegToeAanBoom(positiesVoorHint, null);
  berekenen();
 }

 void voegToeAanBoom(ArrayList<Integer> nieuwePositie, ArrayList<Integer> oudePositie)
 {
  if (!boom.containsKey(nieuwePositie))
  {
   wachtrij.add(nieuwePositie);
   boom.put(nieuwePositie, oudePositie);
  }
 }

 void berekenen()
 {
  while (oplossingspad == null)
  {
   System.out.println(wachtrij + " voor remove");
   ArrayList<Integer> lijst = this.wachtrij.remove();
   System.out.println(wachtrij + " na remove");
   this.UP (lijst);
   this.DOWN (lijst);
   this.LEFT (lijst);
   this.RIGHT (lijst); 
  }
 }

 private void testPuzzelOpgelost(ArrayList<Integer> positiesVoorBeweging,     ArrayList<Integer> positiesNaBeweging)
 {
  System.out.println("Test wordt uitgevoerd");
  System.out.println(positiesVoorBeweging + " positiesVoorBeweging in de testPuzzel");
  System.out.println(positiesNaBeweging + " positiesNaBeweging in de testPuzzel");

  voegToeAanBoom (positiesNaBeweging, positiesVoorBeweging);

  if (positiesNaBeweging.equals(oplossingsposities))
  {
   ArrayList<Integer> zoekPositie = positiesNaBeweging;
   oplossingspad = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
   while (zoekPositie != null)
   {
    oplossingspad.add(0, zoekPositie);
    zoekPositie = boom.get(zoekPositie);
   }
  }
 }

 void UP (ArrayList<Integer> positiesVoorBeweging)
 {
  int indexLeegStukje = positiesVoorBeweging.indexOf(dimensie*dimensie);

  ArrayList<Integer> cloneLijst = (ArrayList<Integer>) positiesVoorBeweging.clone();
  meestRecentePosities = bew.UP(dimensie, positiesVoorBeweging, indexLeegStukje);

  if(meestRecentePosities != cloneLijst)
  {
   testPuzzelOpgelost(cloneLijst, meestRecentePosities);
  }
 }

 void DOWN (ArrayList<Integer> positiesVoorBeweging)
 {
  int indexLeegStukje = positiesVoorBeweging.indexOf(dimensie*dimensie);

  ArrayList<Integer> cloneLijst = (ArrayList<Integer>) positiesVoorBeweging.clone();
  meestRecentePosities = bew.DOWN(dimensie, positiesVoorBeweging, indexLeegStukje);

  if(meestRecentePosities != cloneLijst)
  {
   testPuzzelOpgelost(cloneLijst, meestRecentePosities);
  }
 }

 void LEFT (ArrayList<Integer> positiesVoorBeweging)
 {
  int indexLeegStukje = positiesVoorBeweging.indexOf(dimensie*dimensie);

  ArrayList<Integer> cloneLijst = (ArrayList<Integer>) positiesVoorBeweging.clone();
  meestRecentePosities = bew.LEFT(dimensie, positiesVoorBeweging, indexLeegStukje);

  if(meestRecentePosities != cloneLijst)
  {
   testPuzzelOpgelost(cloneLijst, meestRecentePosities);
  }
 }

 void RIGHT (ArrayList<Integer> positiesVoorBeweging)
 {
  int indexLeegStukje = positiesVoorBeweging.indexOf(dimensie*dimensie);

  ArrayList<Integer> cloneLijst = (ArrayList<Integer>) positiesVoorBeweging.clone();
  meestRecentePosities = bew.RIGHT(dimensie, positiesVoorBeweging, indexLeegStukje);

  if(meestRecentePosities != cloneLijst)    
  {
   testPuzzelOpgelost(cloneLijst, meestRecentePosities);
  }
 }
}
```

---

Here is the error code

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:788)
 at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:134)
 at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:481)
 at Mozaiq.HintBerekenen2.berekenen(HintBerekenen2.java:56)
 at Mozaiq.HintBerekenen2.<init>(HintBerekenen2.java:39)
 at Mozaiq.Schuifpuzzelpaneel.HintUitvoeren(Schuifpuzzelpaneel.java:74)
 at Mozaiq.Gamepaneel.actionPerformed(Gamepaneel.java:126)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
```

Comment: Try `!A.equals(B)` instead of `A != B`, because `==` and `!=` check reference (un)equality.

Comment: You should supply the stack trace so that people can help more quickly and easily. Just post it in the same way you did your code.

Comment: Do you mean you get a NoSuchElementException? If so, it's likely to be in one of the calls to ArrayList#get or ArrayList#remove. Unfortunately, you mayhave to find out why the element isn't there. It's worth checking if a value is present rather than getting it blindly.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help already. I added the error code in my question. I'm gonna try and do what you said. Thank you

Comment: It's not working. The problem is he goes UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT,UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT,UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT. Exactly 3 times ( we printed it). So the original arraylist is again that arraylist. He moves 1 piece in a circle, and finally comes to its original state. Then the program crashes.

Comment: It's not easy to debug this without a debugger. Can you include your output log please. The issue is obviously the `#remove` in your `#berekene` method. Given it removes from your `wactrij` queue baed on the content of your `oplossingspad` list, you need to have equal or more elements in `wachtrij` as in `oplossingspad` in each iteration. So your calls to `#UP`, etc through to `#testPuzzelOpgelost` (where `oplossingspad` is populated) are adding more elements than `wachtrij` contains and so it throws. Or the call to add to `wachtrij` in `#voegToeAanBoom is not doing so as it's already present.